# Divergence Equation

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on the open unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is there a vector valued function $F(x,y)$ such that $$\nabla\cdot F=|\nabla u|^2?$$

---

What I tried is the basic steps of expanding $|\nabla u|^2=u_x^2+u_y^2+2u_xu_y$. 
(I am beginning to suspect this is wrong.)

Edit: I see it should be $|\nabla u|^2=u_x^2+u_y^2$, like what Daniel and M10687 say in the comments below.

Then let $F(x,y)=(a(x,y),b(x,y))$.

So the equation to solve is $\nabla\cdot F=a_x+b_y=u_x^2+u_y^2$.

I am stuck at this point.

Thanks for any help!

Some background: the reason I am thinking about this is related to my previous question: [Harmonic function --- Application of Divergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802023/harmonic-function-application-of-divergence-theorem).
I am trying on my own to apply divergence theorem to the previous question.

Update: I tried $F(x,y)=(\frac 13 u_x^3,\frac 13 u_y^3)$. However $\nabla\cdot F=u_x^2u_{xx}+u_y^2u_{yy}$ has extra terms.

Comment: $\lvert (u_x,u_y)\rvert^2 = u_x^2 + u_y^2$

Comment: But isn't $\nabla u =(u_x,u_y)$? How are you getting that for $|\nabla u|^2$?

Comment: Aha... Yes, I was wrong about that.